# Is there any advantage to running a CI server in a single dev environment?

Tags: continuous-integration

I'm working as the sole developer for a company, and also have a consultancy where I periodically do contract work. In both of these areas, I am typically the only developer on each project.

I currently do TDD as much as it makes sense to do so, so most of my software has decent test coverage. Here's what I want to know from you:

Does it make sense for a single dev environment to implement continuous integration? If so, why? If not, why?

I like the idea of continuous integration, but, short of working on a project with at least one more developer, I don't really see the point - or am I missing the point entirely?

Thanks,

- Joe

Comment: This might be better fit for programmers.stackexchange.com. There probably are duplicates already, though.

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/64592/how-many-developers-before-continuous-integration-becomes-effective-for-us and linked questions.

Comment: Ah, that link was perfect. Thanks for pointing me in a good direction, hyde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While continous integration is a great teamwork tool, I believe that it's also a good point in your case.

It's true that you won't verify that your software pieces are working nicely with others' ones (you can try to practice multiple personality... *gollum! gollum! we're going to destroy this branch... NOO, the developer is a good guy...!*), but think about automatic test runs and deployments from a specialized machine.

This is a strong point: develop while another machine is executing tests and deploying your last change. Also, it might help/force you to develop using a self discipline.

Answer (score 1):

In my previous position I was a single_QA responsible for 15 devs project. I had a similar approach as you - TDD. And still I prefer CI, because testing is more than unit tests passing. If I can give you an advice - just adopt whats useful for you from CI process. After all CI was originally intended to be used in combination with automated unit tests written through the practices of test-driven development. *But* if we're going to talk about serious testing - CI is mandatory process. Why - mostly it allows you to automatically run your unit tests periodically and gain results report.  If I was you I'd take these in-mind first:

- build self-testing(after built, all tests should run to confirm expected behavior)
- use separate CI environment will help you when you have a large lib of tests and don't want to interrupt your development process
- staging builds

***Update:***

If you find it useful, feel free to use [my CI implementation](http://myqaengineering.blogspot.com/2014/04/custom-continuous-integration-testing.html) for .Net 4.5

- Cheers